# Run a shellscript if nginx encounter an error?

Tags: nginx, spawn-fcgi

can I config my nginx to run some shell command/script if encounter 5xx error?

My spawn-fcgi crashes often, I have a cronjob restart it periodically, but I think the best solution would be if nginx fail to reach spawn-fcgi then restart it via command.

Answer (score 2):

You could run [monit](http://mmonit.com/monit/) doing like this in the config:

```
check process spawn-fcgi with pidfile /var/run/spawn-fcgi.pid
        start program = "/etc/init.d/spawn-fcgi start"
        stop program = "/etc/init.d/spawn-fcgi stop"
        if failed host localhost port 80 protocol HTTP request /test.php then restart
        if 5 restarts within 5 cycles then timeout
        depends on nginx

check process nginx with pidfile /var/run/nginx.pid
        start program = "/etc/init.d/nginx start"
        stop program = "/etc/init.d/nginx stop"
        if failed host localhost port 80 protocol HTTP request /token.html then restart
        if 5 restarts within 5 cycles then timeout
```

the test.php is just a php file that does echo 'OK'

Of course I supose you already have a spawn-fcgi init script and a PID file.

Answer (score 0):

No, you can not, without patching nginx source, and that would be wrong because nginx can encounter 5xx error on numerous reasons, not only spawn-fcgi crash.

Just run spawn-fcgi under process supervisor, for example [daemon tools](http://cr.yp.to/daemontools.html) or [supervisord](http://supervisord.org/), which you can configure to restart spawn-fcgi when it crashes.

Comment: thanks, but my problem is somehow odd, the spawn-fcgi process is still there, but nginx just can't communicate with it.

Comment: I suggest you to go either php5-cgi under supervisor or php-fpm (if you are using PHP). If you're using ruby or python, there's uwsgi and rack :-)

Answer (score -2):

You could write an script that connects to your server on port 80 (telnet/curl) and searches for a specified syntax and if it's not available restarts the daemon. You could take it out of the serverheader I guess?

Comment: How that is different on restarting spawn-fcgi in cron in terms of avoiding 502 error ?

Comment: Not, other than restarting it only when it encounters the error. It's better to avoid the error at all.